# INSERT after a cascading DELETE with concurrent transactions

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  id VARCHAR
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE t2 (
  id VARCHAR
  t1_id VARCHAR
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
  FOREIGN KEY (t1_id) REFERENCES t1 (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

Now suppose I ran the following transaction, where a separate transaction runs precisely after the delete:

```
BEGIN;
DELETE FROM t1 where id = 'id';
  -- other transaction, INSERT INTO t2 (id, t1_id) VALUES ('other2', 'id'); --
INSERT INTO t1 (id) VALUES ('id');
INSERT INTO t2 (id, t1_id) VALUES ('other', 'id');
COMMIT;
```

Would the other transaction fail? My understanding from the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/transaction-iso.html) is that it would, since it would wait for the first DELETE to finish.

If I wanted that second transaction to wait for the following INSERTS to complete, would I require an explicit lock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tested this in postgres 9.5 and it works as you describe it. Including it working with an explicit lock:

```
BEGIN;
LOCK t1;
DELETE FROM t1 where id = 'id';
  -- other transaction, INSERT INTO t2 (id, t1_id) VALUES ('other2', 'id'); --
INSERT INTO t1 (id) VALUES ('id');
INSERT INTO t2 (id, t1_id) VALUES ('other', 'id');
COMMIT;
```

the other transaction now completes successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Your query's correct, if there is only one user running the code. It runs top-bottom and you don't need any locks. But if multiple users may run it, you can lock the t1, do your delete and insert then release the lock.